# android placing objects below an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have to create a horizontally aligned textview and an imageview that is placed below of another image view. The problem is they are not getting horizontally aligned. What should i be doing to avoid this problem?..

Whats happening right now:
[image]

It should be like this:
[image]

My Code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem">
    </TextView>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtName"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as (edit dimens according to use):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp"
>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnItem"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
</TextView>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtName"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtName"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imgBtnItem">
</ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i dont know what youve done but it worked!. I still really hate designing android layouts though. thank you for your help!

Comment: @zxc, If you want your layout to be related to each other use relativelayout, I did the same where each below item is related to the main Imageview.

Answer (score 1):

You may try out the following XML code. I have run this and it's doing ok. I have added some icons and text for testing you may change according to your need.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        </ImageButton>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">
            </TextView>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnItem"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtName"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Tested code. dont use Relative layout for simple layout. It's not good practise

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/amojee_logo"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:text="hi how are you"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/amojee_logo"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```